# Github page contains recent changes, but lost updated files in corresponding master repo & local drive

Tags: git, github

So, an odd thing happened when I pushed all of today's work - saved repeatedly throughout the day - to my Github master repo AND a push from the master to its gh-page branch; I checked the corresponding link: all was well, I could see that all of the work I did today within the gh pages and did a fist pump. All was looking good.

Now when I went back to the local files to do more work, to my surprise, none of the changes I made today were there. All the image files I had created were gone from the image folder, none of the code I had written today were showing. It somehow reverted back to its previous state, before today's work. @#)($*@#.

So, where did I go so wrong? How can I get the files from gh pages BACK into my master/local drive?

Comment: Are you convinced that you committed the changes to git? If so, it’s just a matter of figuring out where they are. Maybe use the reflog to find them?

Comment: @evolutionxbox - thanks, I was able to retrieve my old files, forgot to check the gh branch. Lo and behold, my files were there. You can bet this is a mistake I won't be repeating anytime too soon!